# How do wizards/witches in the Harry Potter universe learn non-magic subjects?

Tags: harry-potter

In the *Harry Potter* series, there is a lot of talk about the curriculum at Hogwarts but they never talk about learning math, Muggle history, advanced reading/writing, etc.

Are we to believe they are learning these as well, but they are just less interesting as topics for a book/movie? Or do magical people have no use for learning those past the age of 10?

Comment: advanced reading/writing ??

Comment: It is not really a duplicate, because the other question is about Hogwarts. It's well known from the books that the subjects mentioned here are not taught at Hogwarts, so the point here seems to be whether these subject are taught somewhere else.